# Audio problem in Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: sound

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu for the first time, in dual mode with windows, and the only drawback is that you do not hear the sounds, when playing something is silent, is settings appears that fictitious output, also does not work the microphone, with windows I have no problem.

Here I leave information of my equipment, and I appreciate if you can help me, thank you.

```
juan@Juanpe:~$ inxi -Fxznr
System:
  Kernel: 5.19.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.5
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Compumax product: ONIX-CEL-0001 v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Compumax model: ONIX-CEL-0001 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: GL117E date: 08/09/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 16.0 Wh (42.1%) condition: 38.0/N/A Wh volts: 7.9
    min: 7.6 model: N/A status: Charging
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Celeron N4020 bits: 64 type: MCP
    arch: Goldmont Plus rev: 8 cache: L1: 112 KiB L2: 4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 796 min/max: 800/2800 cores: 1: 796 2: 796
    bogomips: 4377
  Flags: ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel GeminiLake [UHD Graphics 600] driver: i915 v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: Y Media USB Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-6:3
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 resolution: 1360x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
    direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio
    vendor: Realtek driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:0e.0
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-43-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: rtw_8821ce v: N/A port: e000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter type: USB driver: r8152
    bus-ID: 1-8:4
  IF: enx160901104eff state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-4:2
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.2
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 13.61 GiB (2.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Western Digital model: WD5000LPZX-22Z10T0
    size: 465.76 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 28.67 GiB used: 13.58 GiB (47.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 496 MiB used: 33.4 MiB (6.7%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 3.07 GiB used: 59.6 MiB (1.9%)
    file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 1740
Info:
  Processes: 222 Uptime: 1h 3m Memory: 3.67 GiB used: 2.33 GiB (63.6%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  inxi: 3.3.13
```